# how to slice MultiIndex DataFrame with dependent levels of MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with 4 levels of a MultiIndex. I am trying to select rows which has different level 4 indexes for each level 1 indexses.

example:

```
In [68]: df = pd.DataFrame({'i1':[1,1,1,2,2,2],
                        'i2':[1,1,2,1,1,2],
                        'i3':[1,1,1,1,1,1],
                        'i4':[0,1,2,0,1,2],
                        'data':[1,1,2,2,1,1]}).set_index(['i1','i2','i3','i4'])


In [69]: df
Out[69]:
             data
i1 i2 i3 i4
1  1  1  0      1
         1      1
   2  1  2      2
2  1  1  0      2
         1      1
   2  1  2      1
```

Now I want to get indexses as follows:

index i4 in [0, 1] for index i1 = 1

index i4 in [1, 2] for index i1 = 2

```
                 data
i1 i2 i3 i4
1  1  1  0      1
         1      1
2  1  1  1      1
   2  1  2      1
```

For now this works:

```
    cond1 = (df.index.get_level_values('i1') == 1) & (df.index.get_level_values('i4').isin([0,1]))
    cond2 = (df.index.get_level_values('i1') == 2) & (df.index.get_level_values('i4').isin([1,2]))
    .
    .
    .
    condN = ...
    df[cond1 | cond2 | ... | condN]
```

but it looks like bad solution.
Is there any clever way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make this a bit easier with [`IndexSlice`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers), as follows:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
index1 = idx[1, :, :, 0:1]
index2 = idx[2, :, :, 1:2]
pd.concat([df.loc[index1], df.loc[index2]])
```

If you have many indices you need to create, you can store those indices in a dataframe and iterate over that dataframe to create your various slices and then use a list comprehension in `pd.concat` to get your final object. Below, x['id1'] is assumed to be the value you want `id1` to have, and I also make the assumption that you want to limit the same two index columns.

```
indices = [
    idx[
        x['id1'],
        lambda x['id2']: x['id2'] or slice(None),
        lambda x['id3']: x['id3'] or slice(None),
        x['id4']
    ] for x in index_df.iterrows()
]
pd.concat([df.loc[i] for i in indices])
```